# Deploy Ember client on Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, ember.js, tomcat7, ember-cli

I need to deploy an Ember client locally, on a Tomcat server. I added a Tomcat server in Eclipse, and associated my Ember client to it. Thus, theoretically, when starting the server, the client should be launched.

However, when I start the server, I get a 404 error:

> 404 "The requested resource is not available"

Is there anyone here, who has managed to deploy an Ember client on a Tomcat server? If so, could you kindly detail the steps that were taken in order to achieve this objective?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that you have run the [`ember build` command](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#using-ember-cli), which will build the Ember application into its `/dist` directory.

Then, be sure to copy or reference the contents of the Ember `/dist` directory in the [Tomcat `(APPLICATION_BASE)/webapps/ROOT` directory](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application.3F), to make the Ember app the default web application on that server.

Using a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) is a convenient way of ensuring that the Tomcat `ROOT` references the latest from your Ember `/dist` directory.

Restart Tomcat, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you, i will try this out asap and let you know.

Comment: thank you, there is a holdup in the project. That's why i haven't had time to try this out. But i will asap, and i will let you know.

Comment: We are going to use Websphere instead. Could you kindly have a look at my question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976519/deploy-ember-on-websphere?noredirect=1#comment71135302_41976519