# Deploy Ember on Websphere

Tags: ember.js, websphere

I tried to upload an `ember-client` on `Websphere` (8.5.5.11). I did not get any error messages and the output suggests that the client is actually deployed. Some information:

> baseURL: '/', LocationType: 'hash'

However, when i input the following url: http://localhost:9080/, i get the following error message: **Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: {0}**

Looking in the console i see the following message each time i try to access the link above: .org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter INFO: loaded (conf ok)

I had a look at the trace.log file in Websphere, and there is a message as follows: **No web extension processor found for welcome file:/index.html**. Could that be the problem also?
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: do you have a web.xml? how do you configure it?

Comment: The project has a web.xml under target. Is that what you are referring to? Also please do explain what you mean by configure. Worth noting, this is the first time im working with Ember and Websphere. So detailed explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a welcome page? Is that index.html of your ember application?

Comment: Yes, in web.xml there is the following: <welcome-file-list> <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> </welcome-file-list>

Comment: Please do let me know if you need additional information.